# Limitless nesting of content in database

Tags: mysql, database, logic, nested

I have some data that looks like this:
    1: Events
    2: Event 1
    3: Event 1.1
    4: Event 2
    5: Event 2.2
    6: Event 2.2.1
    7: Event 2.2.1.1
    8: Event 2.2.1.2
    9: Event 2.2.1.3
    10: Event 2.2.1.3.1
    11: Event 3
    12: Event 4
    13: Event 4.1

Event 1, 2, 3 and 4 would all be nested under 'Events'
Event 1.1 would be nested under Event 1
etc. etc.

How should I store this in the same table in the database? Could I just have another field for which ids to include?

That would look like this:

> **Fields**:
>       id (id of event)
>       name (name of event)
>       ids_to_include (events that happened within this event)

The most that this (example) data is nested, is by 4 levels (2.2.1.3.1). But in my mind I'm thinking historical data, where every single event in history has many more sub-events, so the nesting needs to be limitless. I don't want to create a new table for each "type" of historical event, I'd rather just a table for long-term **periods** (like WW2:1939-1945) which would have no nesting, and **events** which would have as much nesting as needed.

Or am I going about this the entirely wrong way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some models to store hierarchical data in relational tables, the most used two of them being `nested sets` and `adjacency list`.

Depending on the types of the queries you want to run against these models, either can be more efficient.

In `MySQL`, adjacency list is somewhat harder to query, since it requires set recursion which `MySQL` lacks, but still possible.

See this entry in my blog for the comparison of these two models:

- [**Adjacency list vs. nested sets: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

You cad specify a foreing-key reference to parent element:

```
Id    Name        ParentId
==========================
 1    Events      null
 2    Event 1     1
 3    Event 1.1   2
 4    Event 2     1
 5    Event 2.2   4
 . . .
```